# ConstraintLayout child views retain height of 0 when parent view height is reset

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

I have a nested ConstraintLayout that has its own child views inside a LinearLayout. This LinearLayout can then be collapsed or expanded by the user pressing a Button.

[image]

I do this by programatically setting the LinearLayout height to 0 if the UI needs to be collapsed or defining a MeasureSpec and passing this new measured height to the LinearLayout if the UI needs to expanded.

The issue I'm encountering is that this works the first time the user collapses and expands the UI, subsequent interactions leaves a blank space where the ConstraintLayout child views should be. Looking at Layout Inspector it is showing me that the ConstrainLayout child views have a height of 0dp while the the parent ConstraintLayout has the correct height.

[image]

After some debugging it seems that replacing the ConstraintLayout to a LinearLayout fixes this weird height issue but I would like to know what's going on under the hood when the Views are updating their heights.

I've attached my XML layout file and the code that handles the collapse/expand logic below

MainFragment.kt

```
private var isCollapsed = false

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)
    val collapsableView = view.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.nested_content_holder)

    val button = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.collapse_button)
    button.setOnClickListener {

        val newHeight = if (isCollapsed) {
            collapsableView.measure(
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    collapsableView.width,
                    View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY
                ),
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            )
            collapsableView.measuredHeight
        } else {
            0
        }

        val newLayoutParams = collapsableView.layoutParams
        newLayoutParams.height = newHeight
        collapsableView.layoutParams = newLayoutParams

        isCollapsed = !isCollapsed
    }

    return view
}
```

main_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.MainFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/collapse_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="collapse" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="I am a title" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/nested_content_holder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/teal_700"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/child_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:text="I am a child One"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/child_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:text="I am a child Two"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/nested_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_one"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                    android:text="I am a Nested list item one"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_two"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                    android:text="I am a Nested list item two"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/item_one" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Which version of ConstraintLayout are you using?

Comment: @Cheticamp I'm using constrant layout version 2.0.4.

Comment: Looks like a problem with 2.0.4. It doesn't happen in 2.1.3. If you can't update to the later version, call `requestLayout()` on the errant _ConstraintLayout_ when the size is changed.

Comment: Thanks @Cheticamp. I updated the ConstraintLayout version to 2.1.3 and can cofirm that the issue is gone. Seems like it was a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Just as I understand, the desired behavior is that when the button is clicked, the linear layout is either shown or not.

If I'm right, then I think you are complicating too much.

Have you considered changing your linear layout visibility from View.VISIBLE to View.GONE instead?

```
    override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)
    val collapsableView = view.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.nested_content_holder)

    val button = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.collapse_button)
    button.setOnClickListener {

        if (isCollapsed) {
            collapsableView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            collapsableView.visibility = View.GONE
        }

        isCollapsed = !isCollapsed
    }

    return view
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @teresitaferme The issue seemed to be a bug in an old version of ConstraintLayout. Updating my app to use v2.1.3 solved my issue.